# Update progress not working only in JQuery 3.1.1

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I was trying to update the Jquery version from 1.4.4 to 3.1.1. The updateprogress was working fine in the ASP. Net c# code for older versions. Where as the code is not working ofr JQuery 3.1.1. The update message will keep on loading even after the event trigger is completed in back end. Also this is important to update the version to 3.1.1.
Please help me friends. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: Please give some code - what update progress ? there are too many update progress - also what javascript error you get ?